# Dynamically change chromecast receiver ID on the fly

Tags: android, chromecast

I have Chromecast receiver ID I need to change on the fly.

```
    override fun getAdditionalSessionProviders(context: Context?): MutableList<SessionProvider>? {
        return null
    }

    override fun getCastOptions(context: Context?): CastOptions {
        val notificationOptions = NotificationOptions.Builder()
            .setTargetActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity::class.java.name)
            .build()
        val mediaOptions = CastMediaOptions.Builder()
            .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
            .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity::class.java.name)
            .build()

        return CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(R.id.cast_id) // <-- This needs to be dynamic.
            .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
            .build()
    }
}
```

I need to have it changed by our testers dynamically, ideally by user entering the ID on textfield and then relaunching the app.

I'm able to change it using build variants, but ideally I want it to be fully dynamic.

Comment: Put edittext and get the value from edittext and put inside .setReceiverApplicationId

Comment: As an additional to the answer above, you can refer to the documentation of [`EditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) for guide on how to implement it.